# Chess in comics

Tags: reference-request

Not sure if this is the right place...

I would need no help in compiling a list of chess movies or even chess literature scenes. Comics, though, are a more fleeting medium, and here a list would be much harder to come by. (Obviously I googled beforehand, a bit has been done already.) I prefer examples with actual plot relevance, though, and with actual valid chess. (E.g. Prince Valiant pulling the good old stalemate-with-living-pieces defense.) The obscurer, the merrier.

But specifically (and that's my real question), for 40 years I'm looking for the source of:

a) a Mickey and Goofy adventure. They have to solve a chess problem. Goofy being Goofy inadvertently misplaced a piece, leading to a wrong solution and the good old ACME trapdoor.

b) a SF in a B/W magazine (Eerie or Creepy would be my first guess), where chess is never even mentioned, but as a FM, I immediately recognized the spaceship formations as executing a smothered mate (metaphorical plot relevance alert!).

Comment: I doubt is any use, but just in case a google of "Mickey and Goofy chess cartoon" shows up this https://www.flickr.com/photos/135102934@N08/40830427873

Comment: I don't know about the Mickey and Goofy and story, but generally you can find several chess related Disney comics by searching for "chess" at the international Disney comics index at inducks.org. In particular I think you would be interested in the story "Chess Nuts" from 2014 (not published in English) which is created with help from Magnus Carlsen. https://inducks.org/story.php?c=D+2014-047

Comment: @pst: Oh, definitely :-) (Also definitely, the story I seek can't be found this way.)

Comment: Maybe it can be identified (I'm connected to several Disney comics experts) if you can say a bit more about its publication. If you've read it probably you know that it has been published in a certain country in a certain interval of years.

Comment: @pst: 1970+- (rather -), Germany.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this suits your question. Here is a recent reference in a [web comic.](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2021/03/04/1251-pony/) Sandra and Woo by Novil and Powree.

Comment: Is querent asking for references to chess in comics, "The obscurer, the merrier"? Or does he insist on only hearing about two such references, the Disney story and the scifi story? Hard to tell from the question. - Perhaps @Hauke will care to clarify this point.

Comment: At everyone: I appreciate obscure chess references (THX @A.I.Breveleri!), but to my best knowledge, CSE doesn't have a "site wiki" feature as e.g. MathOverflow (where it is allowed to ask questions that may be answered by a random example), which is why I specifically asked for the two references that I burn to know. Everything else is "bonus". (Maybe the mods can clarify what are the rules w/r/t long lists? I tried the reference questions already on chess fora, but to no avail either.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann list questions are a bad fit for Stack Exchange, see e.g. [Are list questions off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Sounds reasonable, duely noted.